# how to template a listview item / wpf

Tags: wpf, listview, templates

I am trying to achieve this using Expression Blend 3. I need that every listview item to contain an image, followed by a text. ItemTemplate doesn't seem to work.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listview is differnt then the List control.  For ListView you have to add a "View" to the object, then define your columns.

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Column 1" />
            <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Column 2" />
            <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Column 3" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

you should check [this tutorial](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-using-the-listview-part-1).